# is it possible to upload file without form using extjs 4?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

is it possible to upload file without form submit using extjs 4?
what is the way to do that?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You can do it with Ajax and FormData API:

```
var file = s.fileInputEl.dom.files[0],
     data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/upload/files',
   rawData: data,
   headers: {'Content-Type':null}, //to use content type of FormData
   success: function(response){
   }
});
```

See online demo [here](https://ext4all.com/post/extjs-6-ajax-file-upload.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Use 'filefield' control of Extjs 4. and check below links
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.File

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-isFileUpload

I didn't check the same but i think it should help.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: I am also trying to use the same functionality but not getting anywhere. here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571627/adding-csv-upload-browse-button-to-ext-action