# Adding CSV upload browse button to Ext.Action

Tags: file-upload, extjs, csv, openlayers, extjs3

I am trying to create a CSV File upload on GeoExt Map App.
I need to place the upload function within the Ext.Action, so that I can add it to the toolbar of the GeoExt Panel. I am trying to implement this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File). Here is my code,

```
    action = new Ext.Action({
    text: "Upload Excel",
    control: Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Upload a CSV File',
        width: 400,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        frame: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'filefield',
            name: 'csv',
            fieldLabel: 'CSV Upload',
            labelWidth: 50,
            msgTarget: 'side',
            allowBlank: false,
            buttonText: 'Select CSV File'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Upload',
            handler: function () {
                var form = this.up('form')
                    .getForm();
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    form.submit({
                        url: 'file-upload.py',
                        waitMsg: 'Uploading the CSV File...',
                        success: function (fp, o) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your csv file "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    }),
    map: map,
    // button options
    tooltip: "Upload CSV File",
    // check item options
    group: "newTool"
});
actions["upCSV"] = action;
toolbarItems.push(new Ext.button.Button(action));
```

Firebug keeps giving me this error,

`TypeError: b[d.xtype || e] is not a constructor`

Am I declaring the function incorrectly within the Ext.Action?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I am running into the same issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly push the `action` into a `toolbar` since an `Ext.Action` is not a type of `Ext.Component`. An `Ext.Action` is basically a means of creating an abstraction layer which can be reused multiple times. Here you need to do the following:

```
toolbarItems.push(new Ext.button.Button(action));
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Action):

> Actions let you share handlers, configuration options and UI updates
>   across any components that support the Action interface (primarily
>   Ext.toolbar.Toolbar, Ext.button.Button and Ext.menu.Menu components)

Comment: And then how do I add functionality to that button?

Comment: Like I stated in the answer `toolbarItems.push(new Ext.button.Button(action));`

Comment: I updated the code but the error still persists. It is still giving me the same error. You can see the error in the firebug, http://128.196.142.12/geo/test/test_new.html.

Comment: You can't use `new Ext.create()`. That's the problem. It should only be `Ext.create`.

Comment: Sorry, it is still not working. I updated the code.
It continues to give me the same error.

Comment: Hi @VarunAchar still stuck on this

Comment: Sorry.. Wasn't online these past few days. Anyway! You're using Ext JS 3.4 in your application! The part where the bug is, is code that is used for Ext JS 4! Change it to what is acceptable to [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext-method-create)

Comment: I am new to ExtJS can you also provide a example?

Comment: hi varun, sorry to bother you but can we chat here, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18757/room-for-sam007-and-varun-achar

Comment: replied on the chat. It seems that we do not get notified when there is a response on the chat in the notification. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18757/room-for-sam007-and-varun-achar